# Optimal SQLite Query Remove Duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables with the following setup:

```
category: (id, name)
item: (id, name, category_id) - category_id is foreign key to category table
```

Now I am writing a query to retrieve a subset from the category table of only used categories:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c
WHERE  c.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT category_id FROM item)
```

The above query works fine.  I'm just wondering if this is the most optimal way of doing the query or if there's something else that I could do via a join or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transforming the `IN (SELECT)` to `EXISTS (SELECT ... WHERE )` might help:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM item WHERE item.category_id = c.id)
```

Another possibility (I expect it to be slower, but it always depends on your db):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c
INNER JOIN item ON item.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Or you could use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c
INNER JOIN item ON item.category_id = c.id
```

And if speed is that important, don't forget to call `ANALYZE` from time to time:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html

Some other variants for fun:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT item.category_id ) AS i_c ON i_c.category_id = c.id
```

Another:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c

EXCEPT

SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c
LEFT JOIN item ON item.category_id = c.id
WHERE item.category_id IS NULL
```

Comment: My bet is on the query, just after *"fun"*.

Answer (score 0):

Use Join:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM   category c
JOIN item i on c.id=i.category_id 
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```